# How this type of initialization of variable in JS is called

Tags: javascript, variables, initialization

let arr = [1,2,3]
let [a,b,c] = arr; <= How this type of initialization of variables is called

Comment: Its called "Destructuring assignments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called destructuring assignment in JavaScript.

> The [destructuring
>   assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
>   syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack
>   values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct
>   variables.

In your example `let [a,b,c] = arr;`, you are **unpacking** the source object `arr`, and assigning them to 3 variables `a`, `b` and `c`.

We already saw one example of destructuring assignment on an array above.

The general form of the syntax is:

[**`[ variable1, variable2, ..., variableN ] = array;`**](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)

This will just assign `variable1` through `variableN` to the corresponding item in the `array`. *If you want to declare your variables* at the same time, you can add a `var`, `let`, or `const` in front of the assignment:

```
var [ variable1, variable2, ..., variableN ] = array;
let [ variable1, variable2, ..., variableN ] = array;
const [ variable1, variable2, ..., variableN ] = array;
```